# Got this error while installing RouterSplot on termux

Tags: python, termux

```
=============================DEBUG ASSISTANCE=============================
          If you are seeing a compilation error please try the following steps to
          successfully install cryptography:
          1) Upgrade to the latest pip and try again. This will fix errors for most
             users. See: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#upgrading-pip
          2) Read https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/ for specific
             instructions for your platform.
          3) Check our frequently asked questions for more information:
             https://cryptography.io/en/latest/faq/
          4) Ensure you have a recent Rust toolchain installed:
             https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/#rust

          Python: 3.10.4
          platform: Linux-4.9.190-perf-g56d95b3-armv8l-with-libc
          pip: n/a
          setuptools: 62.3.2
          setuptools_rust: 1.3.0
          =============================DEBUG ASSISTANCE=============================

      error: cargo failed with code: 101

      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for cryptography
Failed to build cryptography
ERROR: Could not build wheels for cryptography, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: Did you try any of those four steps?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.